# Box-Behnken vs Central Composite Design

Tags: experiment-design

So, I want to use either a **Box-Behnken (BB)** or a **(circumscribed) Central Composite Design (CCD)** for my 3-factor Response Surface design of experiments (DoE) and to build a linear regression model. I am well aware of the structural difference between these two, such as:

- **BB** requires 3 different levels for each factor and 15 runs (for 3 factors). **CCD** on the other hand, requires 5 different levels and 20 runs (for 6 central points). This means it is significantly easier for DoE rather than for **BB**, as less time will be required and no runs will include factors outside the min/max values of the studied area.
- **CCD** can augment an existing factorial design while the **BB** cannot, but this is not a requirement in my case.
- **BB** has "missing corners" which might lead to worse quality of the regression model, but avoids combined factor extremes. So that is another tradeoff.

The above indicate that I should probably go with the **CCD**, unless I cannot run all the experiments due to some limitation, as extreme levels or too many runs, in which case I will select the **BB**.

Is this a good approach? Can I create a general guideline for an end-user like this: "Always use **CCD**, **unless** you cannot" or there are cases where the BB might perform equally and save time/hassle or maybe even better? I have failed to find good comparisons between the two in literature or methodologies of which one to use in which cases.

Comment: This is a very thoughtful question.  I don't have the answer but I can recommend the book by Box, Hunter and Hunter which was published by Wiley. The two Hunters are J. Stuart Hunter and the late William Hunter. The books title is "Statistics for Experimenters".  Box is of course George E. P. Box.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, I haven't read it but I will sure do so. However, having read "Design and Analysis of Experiments" by D. C. Montgomery, usually these kind of books analyse the different approaches and let the user reach to a conclusion, based on the pros and cons and the user's specific needs. I hope "Statistics for Experimenters" has something more to offer, although I know what I am asking for is more of a research question.